# ID Path for Specified Store, Request Path for Specified Store already exist

Tags: url-rewrite, ce-1.9.1.0

```
/index.php/admin/urlrewrite/save/key/9ea46b0d697..../ ID Path for Specified Store, Request Path for Specified Store already exist.
```

how can I resolve above error.

```
Magento ver. 1.9.1.0
```

Comment: Hello. I think your requested path or id path already created in Url Rewrite Management. So you have to try with removing that.

Comment: Yes. request path used. but I want to use that request path in target path so is it possible

Comment: like : request_path:woca-shop. now i want to rewrite woca-shop-white redirect to woca-shop.

Comment: Yes you can do it but you have to first check that request path "woca-shop-white" is not already exist in Url Rewrite, if it exist then you have to delete that Rewrite and create new custom Rewrite.